# About iframe.contentWindow

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a browser extension, and I need to extract the contentWindow of an iframe. However, it doesn't seem to work correctly. The value of contentWindow printed from the extension is different from the one I manually printed in the console (the console output is the expected one). Do you know how I can fix this error? The src of the iframe is also in the same domain as the document.

console :
[(I need 'Entry')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJAnN.png)

extension :
[(No 'Entry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcDG0.png)

I needed to extract the contentWindow to access the 'Entry', but when I retrieved it from the extension, the contentWindow didn't have the 'Entry', and it appeared as undefined.

Comment: It looks like you're accessing it before the page has fully loaded, so none of the libraries are loaded and the DOM hasn't been updated.

Comment: So, I tried using setInterval to continuously output it, but the same issue keeps recurring.